# tryparse a value form a file

Tags: parsing, try-catch

what i am trying to do is take the variable from the file but throw an exception if input is not a number. i just want an error message to show when the entered amount is a word or negative number. i want to use a try catch but am not sure how to structure it. thanks you guys.

```
 StreamReader read = new StreamReader("../../data.dat");
        Stopwatch st = new Stopwatch();
        bool ok;
        int num;
        string input=(read.ReadLine());
        ok = int.TryParse(input, out num);
        if (ok ==false)
        {
            throw new Exception("Input in incorrect format");
        }
        int sum = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner("../../data.dat");
int num = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
try {
    num = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Input in incorrect format.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
scan.close();
```